# Multi Projects with CCNET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have GIT repo as below,

```
 \main
       \Module A
       \Module B
       \Shared
```

When i make a change on Module B, CCNET will make a build from Module A and then Module B,
I dont want CCNET to do this way.It will take a lot of time.
I just want ccnet build only changes on Module B.

Somebody please help me :
My 1 project in CCNET Config:

```
enter code here
   <project name="Dashboard 5.0" queue="Dashboard_01" queuePriority="01" category="01">
<artifactDirectory>&pathToArtifactsDirectory;Dashboard 5.0\</artifactDirectory>
&workingDirectory;
<webURL>http://&buildServerAddress;/ccnet/server/&buildServerName;/project/Dashboard 5.0/ViewLatestBuildReport.aspx</webURL>
&modificationDelaySeconds;
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger seconds='30' buildCondition='IfModificationExists'/>
  <scheduleTrigger time='03:00' buildCondition='ForceBuild' name='Scheduled'/>
  <scheduleTrigger time='11:00' buildCondition='ForceBuild' name='Scheduled'/>
</triggers>
<state type="state" directory="&pathToStatesDirectory;Dashboard 5.0\" />

    <sourcecontrol type="git">
      <repository>&gitAddress;</repository>
      <branch>master</branch>
      <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
      <fetchSubmodules>false</fetchSubmodules>
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>

      <commitBuildModifications>false</commitBuildModifications>
      <commitUntrackedFiles>false</commitUntrackedFiles>
      <timeout>3000000</timeout>
    </sourcecontrol>


<tasks>
  <nant>
    <executable>&pathToNantFile;</executable>
    <baseDirectory>&pathToBuildScriptsDirectory;Dashboard 5.0\</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-D:projects_to_build=dashboard_framework</buildArgs>
    <buildFile>cruise.build</buildFile>
    <targetList>
      <target>automate</target>
    </targetList>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>3000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </nant>

</tasks>
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\*Test.dll-results.xml</file>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\Test*.dll-results.xml</file>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\simian.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
</publishers>
```

Comment: These are seperate projects or seperate modules of same project? Whether these modules can be build seperately?

Comment: Yes,these modules can be built seperately.I dont know how to let CCNET make build only the module which has the file in its folder changes.

Answer (score 1):

Any check in for Module A or Module B will cause the project node to start either way. What you are looking for is similar to what subversion update command on a sub folder does and Git is not intended to be this way. An alternative you can create a separate repository for each module. The build script or Nant task would have to be separated as well.

In Git, if you have several directories that are always checked out independently, then these are really two different projects and should live in two different repositories. You can merge them back together at a later point using [Git Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)